# The quartic congruence $ax^4+bx^2+c \equiv 0 \pmod {m}$ and a quadratic congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

We know that the quartic diophnatine equation $$ax^4+bx^2+c=0$$ has integer solutions if and only if the quadratic equation $$at^2+bt+c=0$$ has integer solutions. Here we set $x^2=t$

Let $m≥2$ be a positive integer. I am asking about the validity of this claim:

**Claim**: The quartic congruence $$ax^4+bx^2+c \equiv 0 \pmod {m}$$ has integer solutions if and only if the quadratic congruence $$at^2+bt+c \equiv 0 \pmod {m}$$ has integer solutions.

Comment: The claim in the first paragraph is obviously false. We don't know that. For example 
$t^2+3t+2=0$ has integer solutions $t=-1$ and $t=-2$, but the quartic $x^4+3x^2+2=0$ obviously has no integer solutions.

Comment: For the second statement a similar idea works. If you're mod $m$ take any two quadratic non-residues and consider the quadratic with solutions those non-residues. The quartic will have no solution. For example say $m=5$, then take $(t-2)(t-3)=t^2-5t+6$ clearly has solutions, and $x^4-5x^2+6$ won't because any solution has $2$ or $3$ as a square.

Comment: @askingquestions: I am asking if there is some sufficient and necessary conditions to get tht equivalence.

Comment: I would include what you're asking in the question then. If you're asking about the validity, then the answer is no (as pointed above). From my previous comment it should be quite clear the sufficient and necessary condition is that the quadratic equation has quadratic residue solutions.

Comment: @askingquestions: Can you convert this into a clear proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Claim:** The quartic congruence $$ax^4+bx^2+c\equiv 0 \mod m$$ has integer solutions if and only if the quadratic congruence $$at^2+bt+c\equiv 0\mod m$$ has quadratic residue solutions.

*Proof:* Suppose the quartic congruence has solution $x$, then $t=x^2$ is a quadratic residue mod $m$ and a solution of the quadratic. Suppose now $at^2+bt+c=(t-r^2)(t-s^2)\equiv 0\mod m$, then clearly $x=\pm r,\pm s$ are the solutions of the quartic. Done.